# how i do with php curl loop in the page

Tags: php, loops, curl

i work with curl 
and download a site to my code

this is my code:

```
$data = get_web_page('http://localhost/www/site.html');
$scraped_page = get_web_page('http://localhost/www/site.html');
$scraped_data = scrape_between($data['content'], "<td class=\"category last\"><a href=\"", "\">");
echo $scraped_data;
```

know and i whant all the value i have between this tags:

```
<td class="category last"><a href="
```

value

```
">
```

i have in this page 20 links from that
how i take all the links
and show at my site

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this Html Dom parser library [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)